# write protection mode will not change

Tags: c#, registry, file-attributes

I use this following code to remove the write protection folder so that I can delete that. But It won't work.

```
File.SetAttributes(@"F:\File", FileAttributes.Normal); 
File.Delete(@"F:\File");
```

How can I remove the write protection?

If I can remove file protection from the disk, so give some codes to do that.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between Folder and File. With this you will remove the readonly atribute and delete the folder.

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"F:\File");
di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
di.Delete(true);
```

**EDIT**:

[Formating USB drive](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115598/Formatting-a-Drive-using-C-and-WMI). You can read the article.

```
public static bool FormatDrive(string driveLetter, 
    string fileSystem = "NTFS", bool quickFormat=true, 
    int clusterSize = 8192, string label = "", bool enableCompression = false )
{
   if (driveLetter.Length != 2 || driveLetter[1] != ':'|| !char.IsLetter(driveLetter[0]))
      return false;

   //query and format given drive         
   ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher
    (@"select * from Win32_Volume WHERE DriveLetter = '" + driveLetter + "'");
   foreach (ManagementObject vi in searcher.Get())
   {
      vi.InvokeMethod("Format", new object[] 
    { fileSystem, quickFormat,clusterSize, label, enableCompression });
   }

   return true;
}
```

You should put the driveLetter like this: `"F:"`

Comment: Do you have write protected files in this directory ?

Comment: This file is in USB flash device and the USB flash is write protected. I can't even format the drive

Comment: do you want to delete a File or Directory/Folder ?!

Comment: I want to delete everything I‌ can. I Want to delete all folders and files. Something like formatting cause I can't even format the drive

Comment: I post a code with link to the article how to format USB drive.